# How to distinguish between PWA and TWA in code?

Tags: javascript, css, progressive-web-apps, twa

How can one distinguish between an Android Trusted Web Activity (PWA wrapped in a WebView) and a Progressive Web App that has been added to the home screen (fullscreen mode)?

Is it possible in JS or CSS or even HTML5?

**Edit:** People are asking me what the differences are between a TWA and a PWA. I believe explaining this here is beyond the scope of this question. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: [How can I detect if my website is opened inside a Trusted Web Actvity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580414/how-can-i-detect-if-my-website-is-running-inside-a-trusted-web-actvity)

The question is formulated a bit differently, but it solves my problem as well. In short:

```js
document.referrer.includes('android-app://<twa.package.name>')
```