# Hide div in a Custom Tab opened from a Trusted Web Activity

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity, twa

I have an Android app which uses Trusted Web Activity with an external link. When clicking link it opens in an in-app browser (Custom Tabs). I want hide a div in that Custom Tabs page, but I want to show that div when the site opens in Chrome. Is it possible? The div is like below.

`<div id="something" class="something"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="somelink">text</a></div>`

Comment: You can load the page with javascript look at this question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Comment: 1 solution is by detecting the location of the page whether it is on a webview page/regular browser, then do some function to hide the div element. 

Detect webview/browser reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727117/android-webview-user-agent-vs-browser-user-agent

Comment: I have edited my question. It is a TWA app. Not a coder here. Please give answers in simple format.

Comment: Any javascript code to differentiate between android browser and in-app browser that can be inserted/used in website?

Comment: Here's how to detect if a site has been opened by a Trusted Web Activity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580414/how-can-i-detect-if-my-website-is-running-inside-a-trusted-web-actvity/54580415#54580415. But it seems like you want to implement this on a navigation to outside the URL opened in the Trusted Web Activity, with is Custom Tabs, not WebView. Can you confirm?

Comment: I mean I have an external link in twa, which opens in in-app browser. In that in-app browser I want to hide a div, but it should be seen in normal android browser. Hope I was clear. It is not related with twa but related with in-app browser in twa.

Comment: Do you own the page being opened in the in-app browser? If you do, you can append a query parameter to the URL when the user navigates to the in-app browser. If you don't own the page, it's not possible (by design).

Comment: @andreban, Yes I do own the page that being opened in in-app browser

Comment: What query parameter you are referring to.

Comment: Let's say the Trusted Web Activity is openning `https://siteA.com` and `https://siteB.com` is opened, you want to hide a div when siteA opens siteB. You could link to `https://siteB.com?hideDiv=true`. siteA can append the extra parameter only when inside a Trusted Web Activity. siteB checks if the parameters exiss and hides the dive if it is present.

Comment: @andreban Thank you. It worked. I am using a static site as `https://siteB.com`. For me when I use `https://siteB.com?hideDiv=true` and go from `siteA.com`, it worked for the first click. After that `div` shows again. I used code as `<script>
  var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
if(url.searchParams.get("hideDiv")) {
  document.write('<div></div>');
} else {
  document.write('<div id="button"><a class="bdiv" href="link" style="left: 0px;">test</a></div>');
}</script>`

Comment: I mean after first click then I surf through siteB.com, div shows again

Comment: Above code is available to all pages

Comment: Added as an actual answer. Could you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the developer controls both sites involved, if the Trusted Web Activity is opening `https://siteA.com` and `https://siteB.com` is opened from a link on site A and you want to hide a div onlnye when siteA opens siteB.

You could link to `https://siteB.com?hideDiv=true`. siteA can append the extra parameter only when inside a Trusted Web Activity. siteB checks if the parameters exists and hides the dive if it is present.

Another alternative is checking `document.referrer` in JavaScript and checking if it matches `https://siteA.com`.

Comment: It will be usefull if you give full code as I am not a good coder. I have edited my first question. Thank you.

Comment: As I satated in previous comment, for me it doesn't work completely, hence I request you to post full code. Thanks.