# How to hide div in in-app browser or android webview

Tags: android-webview, inappbrowser, trusted-web-activity, twa

I have asked a question in [Hide div in a Custom Tab opened from a Trusted Web Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517599/hide-div-in-a-custom-tab-opened-from-a-trusted-web-activity)
Let me explain a little bit more.

My twa website is https://www.monsoonmalabar.com/
In the above site there is a link to external site which is https://keralapsc.monsoonmalabar.com/ when clicking this link in twa app, this link opens in in-app browser. In that in-app browser(website: https://keralapsc.monsoonmalabar.com) there is a button floats left side with link `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monsoonmalabar.app`.

I want to hide that link(button) when user using twa(in-app browser). According to your suggestion in the stackoverflow site, I added the external link as https://keralapsc.monsoonmalabar.com/?hideDiv=true
And added a code in external site as

```
<script>
  var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
if(url.searchParams.get("hideDiv")) {
  document.write('<div></div>');
} else {
  document.write('<div id="play_button"><a class="btn_openinapp" data-attr="btn_openinapp" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monsoonmalabar.app" style="left: 0px;"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i></a></div>');
}

</script>
```

Now what happens is during the first visit from twa(which has hideDive=true) the button disappears. But when I continue to surf external site by going to another page in that external site button shows again. Maybe I didn't understand you correctly. Can you please explain a little bit more with codes. I am new to coding. My twa app is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monsoonmalabar.app

Below is the screenshot of external link marked.

[image]

Comment: any solutions ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to save the `hideDiv` information into the [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), so you can load the information from there when navigating to other pages.

The code would look something like this:

```js
<script>
  // Set `hideDiv` to `true` on sessionStorage when we receive the `hideDiv` parameter.
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  if(url.searchParams.get('hideDiv')) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('hideDiv', true);
  }

  // sessionStorage is persisted across page loads, but cleared if the tab is closed and
  // a new navigation session starts. We check if it's been set to `true` in this session.
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('hideDiv')) {
    document.write('<div></div>');
  } else {
    document.write('<div id="play_button"><a class="btn_openinapp" data-attr="btn_openinapp" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monsoonmalabar.app" style="left: 0px;"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i></a></div>');
  }
</script>
```