# Detect & prevent opening new tabs inside Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: javascript, android, chrome-custom-tabs

**Background:**

- Our webapp has a feature that sends links by email to users.
- When clicked inside the email, the link should open our webapp.
- Our webapp (window A) includes a few actions that create new tabs because the content cannot be rendered inside an iFrame (window B)
- window A and window B communicate using `postMessage`.

**Problem:**
On Android devices, using the Gmail app, clicking/tapping links in emails open the resulting page inside a `Chrome Custom Tab` browser that properly displays Window A.

However, opening window B will position it over window A. While `postMessage` between the two browsing contexts is working **there is no way for the user to return to Window A**. Back arrow in the browser will return user to Gmail app.

We'd like to detect this situation and gracefully fallback so the user doesn't find themselves stranded on Window B - as we do for other non-multi-tab browsers like WebViews (Facebook, etc).

**Seems that Chrome Custom Tabs uses the exact same user agent as "regular" multi-tab Chrome browser** so that's not an option.

Would appreciate if anyone has figured out a way to detect loading through `Chrome Custom Tabs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Tabs and Trusted Web Activity are largely the same protocol. The solution  described in [How can I detect if my website is opened inside a Trusted Web Actvity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580414/how-can-i-detect-if-my-website-is-opened-inside-a-trusted-web-actvity) should work for Custom Tabs too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @andreban!.
Just FYI - when using Samsung Browser the `refferer == ""` so this method works only between Gmail app and standard Chrome browser

Comment: Just to be more precise on my last comment: 
When Samsung Browser is set as default browser, and webapp is opened by Gmail in Samsung Browser Custom Tabs, the `referrer == ""` so this method works only between Gmail app and standard Chrome browser's Custom Tabs.

Comment: by any chance do you have similar solution for `SFSafariViewController `or `WKWebview`? Those webviews also do not support tabs in proper manner.